# Install COMODO EV SSL Certificate on EC2 Ubuntu Instance

Tags: ubuntu, ssl, https, amazon-ec2

Thanks in advance for any help.

This is my first time setting up HTTPS and I just got the certificate from Comodo but don't know what to do with it. The certificate came in a .zip file with these files inside:

```
Root CA Certificate - AddTrustExternalCARoot.crt
Intermediate CA Certificate - COMODOAddTrustServerCA.crt
Intermediate CA Certificate - COMODOExtendedValidationSecureServerCA.crt
Your COMODO EV SSL Certificate - forum_linma_com.crt
```

I also have it in text format. How do I set it up so my node.js app is accessible via HTTPS? The app is running on an EC2 instance with Ubuntu 13.10 and I'm using SSH to access the server.

**Follow-Up Question**

So I'm still getting an error. Here's the relevant info:

The contents of `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/forumHTTPSconfig` (the only file in sites-enabled):

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
   ServerName forum.figma.com
   SSLEnable
   SSLEngine on
   SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/forum_figma_com.crt
   SSLCertificateKeyFile /home/ubuntu/.ssh/myserver.key
   SSLCACertificateFile /etc/apache2/combined-ca.crt
</VirtualHost>

<IfModule mod_proxy.c>
    <Proxy *>
      SSLProxyEngine on
      Order deny,allow
      Allow from all
    </Proxy>

    RewriteEngine on

    ProxyPass / https://127.0.0.1:3000
    ProxyPassReverse /http://127.0.0.1:3000
</IfModule>
```

Here's the output of my attempts to call `a2enmod`:

```
ubuntu@ip-10-190-91-217:/etc/apache2/sites-enabled$ sudo a2enmod forumHTTPSconfig
ERROR: Module forumHTTPSconfig does not exist!
ubuntu@ip-10-190-91-217:/etc/apache2/sites-enabled$ sudo a2enmod mywebsite
ERROR: Module mywebsite does not exist!
```

Any idea what's going wrong? Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: How did you get the .key file from Comodo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, remember that there's a private `key` file that you used to generate your certs initially. You will need it in your configuration.

1. One way of setting it up is by just configuring HTTPS on your node.js app. You can find more information here:

   http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/https.html
2. Another way of setting it up is by setting up a reverse proxy to your node.js application using either apache or nginx.

**nginx**

Grab all the files:

```
Root CA Certificate - AddTrustExternalCARoot.crt
Intermediate CA Certificate - COMODOAddTrustServerCA.crt
Intermediate CA Certificate - COMODOExtendedValidationSecureServerCA.crt
Your COMODO EV SSL Certificate - forum_linma_com.crt
```

and concatenate all their content into forum_linma_com.crt

Here's a sample configuration:

```
server {
    listen       443;
    server_name  yourdomain.com;

    ssl                  on;
    ssl_certificate      /path/to/forum_linma_com.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key  /path/to/forum_linma_com.key;

    location / {
        proxy_pass  http://localhost:3000;
        proxy_next_upstream error timeout invalid_header http_500 http_502 http_503 http_504;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_buffering off;
        proxy_set_header        Host            static.example.com;
        proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }
}
```

Here's more information for nginx and reverse proxy:

http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpProxyModule

**Apache**

Grab the following:

```
Root CA Certificate - AddTrustExternalCARoot.crt
Intermediate CA Certificate - COMODOAddTrustServerCA.crt
Intermediate CA Certificate - COMODOExtendedValidationSecureServerCA.crt
```

and concatenate all of their content into one file: `combined-ca.crt`

This is an sample config:

```
<VirtualHost 0.0.0.0:443>
   ServerName mydomain.com
   SSLEnable
   SSLEngine on
   SSLCertificateFile /path/to/forum_linma_com.crt
   SSLCertificateKeyFile /path/to/forum_linma_com.key  
   SSLCACertificateFile /path/to/combined-ca.crt

<IfModule mod_proxy.c>
    <Proxy *>
      SSLProxyEngine on
      Order deny,allow
      Allow from all
    </Proxy>

    RewriteEngine on

    ProxyPass / https://127.0.0.1:3000
    ProxyPassReverse /http://127.0.0.1:3000
</IfModule>

</VirtualHost>
```

`3000` is the port where your node.js server is running.

Here's more information for Apache and reverse proxy:

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response, Rico. A couple follow up questions--1. should I add the sample config to the end of apache2.conf? 2. Is it really supposed to be 0.0.0.0:443 or should I put the actual IP address? 3. Should I change the two other addresses (ProxyPass, ProxyPassReverse)? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This is just a clarification from @AaronClayton-Dunn .

> should I add the sample config to the end of apache2.conf?

Since you are using Ubuntu the usual procedure is to create a file: `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/mywebsite` and put the sample content there.

To enabled it you can run:

```
sudo a2dismod default
sudo a2enmod mywebsite
sudo service apache2 restart
```

> Is it really supposed to be 0.0.0.0:443 or should I put the actual IP address?

You can either use 0.0.0.0 or * (star) which basically tells it to listen on any address on your server. No need to put a specific IP address unless you want to restrict access to your web server, meaning that the client would have to use a specific IP address to connect to your server.

> Should I change the two other addresses (ProxyPass, ProxyPassReverse)?

No. Those statements are basically saying forward everything everything that goes to `/` on your site on port 443 to HTTP port 3000 which is where your node.js server is supposed to be running.

Comment: Hi, thanks again for the help Rico. Haha just checked your profile and we happen to live in the same town. Anyway, when I ran "sudo a2dismod default," I got this error: "ERROR: Module default does not exist!" Any idea how to get around that? Thanks!

Comment: That's cool, we are neighbors :-)  So basically `sudo a2dismod default` is disabling the default apache site that is configured when you install apache the first time on Ubuntu. So you got an error because it's probably disabled already. You can check by just running `ls /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/` and if you don't see default then it's not enabled.

Comment: Hmmm...I must be missing something. The contents of /etc/apache2/sites-enabled are 000-default.conf and the file I just created (forumHTTPSconfig) with the config code inside. When I run "sudo a2enmod forumHTTPSconfig", I get the same error: "ERROR: Module forumHTTPSconfig does not exist!" Thanks again for your help.

Comment: Then what you want to run is `a2dissite 000-default` or you can just remove the link which is what the `a2dissite` script is doing: `rm -f /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf`

Comment: Great, `a2dissite 000-default` worked. What's the next step? I tried `sudo a2enmod forumHTTPSconfig` and I got the usual error message.

Comment: `sudo a2enmod mywebsite` and `sudo service apache2 restart`

Comment: Hi @Rico, thanks again for all your help with this. I really appreciate it. I updated my original question with what went wrong when I tried a2enmod. Let me know if you see what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: You need to create a file called `/etc/apache2/sites-available/mywebsite` for `sudo a2enmod mywebsite` to work.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48098/discussion-between-rico-and-aaron-clayton-dunn)

Comment: Driving home. Can help u in about 20 minutes.